# Python variable, in a Jupyter notebook, modified despite no further action to it

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook, global-variables, jupyter

I'm not going to share the direct code since I feel the length of it would bog down anyone's analysis of my main question (though I can share it if absolutely need be). It's best I summarize it.

To put it generally, in a previous cell, I established a pandas dataframe - let's say we call it **original_df** here. In the next cell, I initialize a new variable **temp_df = original_df** so that I may manipulate the same data while keeping the original dataframe in tact. At no point in the code that follows do I ever once assign anything to nor even use **original_df** in any way, yet when I get done manipulating **temp_df** as much as I need to...subsequently checking **original_df** shows that it has changed in all the same ways that **temp_df** did.

Any ideas why this would happen?, some type of environment issue perhaps? Re-running each of the code cells that created **original_df** is rather inconvenient, and putting all of the code in one cell would negate the whole point of using a Jupyter Notebook (given the visuals along the way). I find it incredibly bizarre that this is happening at all, but is there any way to explicitly force a "freeze" on the **original_df** variable while its **temp_df** copy is being manipulated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to copy the dataframe with the libary copy

```
import copy

temp_df = copy.copy(original_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

`temp_df = original_df` only creates a new reference to `original_df`.

You need to call `copy()` on your original dataframe: `temp_df = original_df.copy()` to create a new dataframe.

More info here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Comment: Wow, thank you! I haven't tried it yet but is this distinction a necessity only within Jupyter or for Python in general?

What's the point of the default way (i.e., setting temp=original) if changes to temp are just going to change original anyway? Are there instances where one technique may serve a purpose that the other doesn't?

Comment: This is related to how Python works, so you always need to call copy() when you want to preserve the original DF. I personally never use temp_df = original_df, so I can't think of a case when someone would do that. Perhaps someone else knows an example?